# Why does a simple program import <Foundation/Foundation.h> instead of individual header files?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C. The Xcode generated template code contains:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

When I check it at /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers, there are nearly 2 thousands header files!

My question is, for a really simple code that use only NSString, why not import just the NSString.h file?

Does importing the whole bunch of Foundation framework affect the performance of executables? If not, does it have some benefits?

Comment: Unfortunately the Xcode system is heavily bloated. It is worthwhile to check the size of "Hello World" to see. It is also worthwhile to consider that it all may have been dead-stripped out in the end, but potentially wasting plenty cycles dealing with it beforehand.  Like Swift, Objective C does not really build an application but builds a pseudo-pcode system that basically needs a virtual machine to execute (a runtime).  You can't use Objective C in bare metal development for example because it does not produce raw assembly able to run on it's own.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It doesnt affect the performance as the inbuilt frameworks are all there installed on your device already ready to be linked to by your executable.

What you are saying when you `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` is "I would like access to the functionality of the Foundation framework even if I don't use it all".  Its a semantic division.

The compiler will do all the optimisation that needs doing with respect to discarding unused symbols.

The problem with just doing an import on NSString.h is do you know what dependencies there are for NSString. I don't know, and dont need to either.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect that NSString.h would import its own dependencies?

Comment: @TenMinJoe True. Its not the best written sentence in the world, but it sort of gets the point across that Frameworks imports are atomic. Mess with that at your own peril.

Comment: It actually the linker, not the compiler, that ensures only the used symbols are linked to the final executable. And yes, importing just NSString.h will ensure its own dependencies are imported as well so there is no problem whatsoever to import only NSString.h if you only use NSString. Importing Foundation.h is a convenience in the more typical case that you use more than a single class from the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, consider this really simple code:

```
int main() {
  /* my first program in Objective-C */
  NSLog(@"Hello, World! \n");
  return 0;
}
```

Just trying to print "Hello World" will result in the following error without importing Foundation.h:

```
main.m: In function ‘main’:
main.m:4:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘NSLog’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   NSLog(@"Hello, World! \n");
   ^~~~~
main.m:4:3: error: cannot find interface declaration for ‘NSConstantString’
```

In short, all the basic things which are required to execute a program are automatically included in `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`, such as NSLog in this case.

This is just like `#include <stdio.h>` in C or `#include <iostream.h>` in C++.