# Import one class from a Swift module

Tags: swift, module, foundation

Is it possible to import just one class from a Swift module? I used

```
import struct Foundation.Date
```

but now, `NSString` and other Foundation classes/structs are available too, at the top level!
All I really want is the `Date` class, to avoid polluting the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is originally made for objective-c but the behaviour is the same: [Why does a simple program import <Foundation/Foundation.h> instead of individual header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487285/why-does-a-simple-program-import-foundation-foundation-h-instead-of-individual)

You don't have to worry about that, I think your compiler do this job perfectly ! :)

Comment: yes, but it doesn’t address the namespace pollution issue. I don’t want the symbol `NSString` accessible from my code

Comment: Likewise, I have a framework which defines a fairly generic symbol (Log) - which clashes with a class called Log I have in my surrounding app. It'd be nice to import the framework but leave out the "Log" bit